# How Debian PTS finds that there's a new upstream version?

Tags: debian

For example, the package [aisleriot](http://packages.qa.debian.org/a/aisleriot.html) says:

> A new upstream version is available: 3.12.1, you should consider packaging it.

How does the Package Tracking System knows?

Comment: I'm not sure about the tagging, since there's nothing else that applies.

Answer (score 2):

They watch it! Well, not literally. The Debian Quality Assurance team has a tool to watch upstream releases called `uscan`. It check the entries in the `debian/watch` file of each package and verify those directories for new version of the packages, all in server side, this of course can be used locally too for personal package archives (PPA). An example of the ffc package watch file:

```
cat debian/watch 
version=3
https://bitbucket.org/fenics-project/ffc/downloads/ffc-(.*)\.tar\.gz
```

It tells to check the `https://bitbucket.org/fenics-project/ffc/downloads/` directory, for any file starting with `ffc-`, is 3 versions deep, and ends in `.tar.gz`.

[There's more information in uscan man page.](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=uscan)